# Flutter: Animating a child in a column when state changes

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am implementing the State design pattern for my app.

https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-design-patterns-6-state-be06cb05525c

So each of my states has a render() function which is called by a StreamBuilder in the top level widget.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScrollConfiguration(
        behavior: ScrollBehavior(),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                child: Text("Change State"),
                onPressed: () {
                  state1 = !state1;
                  _changeState(state1 ? State1() : State2());
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 100),
              StreamBuilder(
                    key: ValueKey(state1 ? 20 : 30),
                    initialData: State1(),
                    stream: _stateContext.outState,
                    builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot<IState> snapshot) {
                      return snapshot.data!.render();
                    },
                  ),
            ])));
  }
```

However, I want the change from one state to another to be animated. Eg. If these are my two states:

[image: State1]

[image: State2]

I want to animate the size of the red box when the state changes. How can I achieve this when the widgets to be rendered are rendered by separate classes? I tried setting the key to the same value and using AnimatedSwitcher, but that does seem to work.

Comment: wait, did you mean you used the same key for 2 different widgets? have you tried to use animated container to change the size of the box?

Comment: Sorry, not a well articulated question on my part. The issue is with implementing the State model (when each state corresponds to a different class) and animating transitions between states. AnimatedContainer is the right way to go.